# Can not decrypt HTTPS traffic on my iOS 14 device

Tags: ios, ssl

I have 2 devices with iOS 12 and 14.

Both of them are configured the same way:

1. Certificate is downloaded from http://ipv4.fiddler:8866/
2. Certificate is installed from Settings > Profile Downloaded >DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot

On the iOS 12 device all works like a charm - I can open HTTPS web sites in Safari and inspect the traffic.
But on iOS device I get a warning "This Connection is Not Private", my certificate is not trusted and I can not ignore it by pressing "visit this website"

Any advice where to dig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to enable it in **Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings**